# Is there a way to create a rrule for recurrent events that only fall into weekdays?

Tags: google-calendar-api, recurring-events, rrule

I am trying to user google calendar api to schedule events, 
they have different recurrency types

```
type1: weekly
type2: every 14 days
type3: every 28 days
type4: every 42 days
type5: every 56 days
```

The problem is:
if the 56th day falls on the weekend, the appointment should be moved to monday.

I am new to rrule, and am trying to get my head around this.
Can someone help me to understand a little bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, Just noticed that for this specific answer, all the types are variations for the weekly

```
type1: weekly - weekly :)
type2: every 14 days - weekly, every other week
type3: every 28 days - weekly, every 4 weeks
type4: every 42 days - weekly, every 6 weeks
type5: every 56 days - weekly, every 8 days
```

For the sake of future implementations, and for me to try to understand RRules better, though, let's make this a bit harder, WHAT IF this is something like:

```
type1: weekly
type2: every 13 days
type3: every 27 days
type4: every 41 days
type5: every 55 days
```

Can someone please try and explain me how to go through this issue?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can import `.ics` files into google calendar that define recurring events.  Once imported, they are not editable, however.

This should get you going [How can an ICS file be written for a recurring event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455376/how-can-an-ics-file-be-written-for-a-recurring-event)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I am looking for a RRule to be applied through the google calendar api.
And it needs to be editable too, if the client decides to modify the recurrence.